# sbn.getNotification().extras; in ectras can not resolve error

Tags: java, android

When i try that for reading  all notification  of any application  its cant find extras on android.services.notifi..... plk

When i try that for reading  all notification  of any application  its cant find extras on android.services.notifi..... plk
When i try that for reading  all notification  of any application  its cant find extras on android.services.notifi..... plk

I got one error on below line

```
Bundle extras = sbn.getNotification().extras;
```

So its gave error msg "extras" can not be resolve....

Plz give me solution